# SignalR .NET framework vs SignalR .NET Core feature

Tags: c#, .net, signalr

[This example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-3.1) is from the microsoft docs on SignalR .NET Core on "Create and use hubs":

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SignalRChat.Hubs
{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
        }
    }
}
```

[And this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr) is from the microsoft docs on SignalR .NET Framework on "Create and use hubs":

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
namespace SignalRChat
{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send(string name, string message)
        {
            // Call the broadcastMessage method to update clients.
            Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
        }
    }
}
```

Am I right to assume that SignalR .NET Framework does not supports returnig Task from Client calls while SignalR .NET Core has this functionality? Is it only in .NET Core that we can await calls to Clients to make sure that the message was received?

Comment: No. You need to check the docs, not just the examples. Good examples typically display only a single concept. In this case the relevant docs are the [Asynchronous Execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#asynchronous-execution) section in the [Server Hubs API Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#asynchronous-execution) `The method that you call executes asynchronously.`

Comment: `Is it only in .NET Core that we can await calls to Clients to make sure that the message was received?` that's a different question, and you *can't* make sure the message was received just by waiting

Answer (score 0):

If you override the base hub methods you can see that they return a `Task`, so you can make the other methods to return a Task as well and make them `async`.

```cs
public override Task OnConnected()
{
    return base.OnConnected();
}

public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
{
    return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
}

public override Task OnReconnected()
{
    return base.OnReconnected();
}
```